# Replacing <br> by <p>

Tags: jquery

Replacing Break lines, html.

ex:

```
alert($("#page").find('br').eq(5).html('<p> test </ p>'));
```

Needed to find the 5 the 10 and the 15 business and replace it with an HTML content ...

Comment: Can you add the html that goes along with the function?  You can create working code at https://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
$("#page").find('br:nth-child(5n)').replaceWith('<p> test </p>');
```

This will replace every fifth `<br>` tag with `<p> test </p>`. The code that you wrote originally was modifying the innerHTML of the `<br>` tag, which isn't something you can do. It would have resulted in something like `<br><p> test </p></br>` if `<br>` tags weren't self-closing.